# Parallel API requests using Spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.4.0 and Scala 2.11.
I have Dataset[Users] , when Users consists of: (country,id,url).
I want to group this DS by country, and for each group , 
make request for the URL , to get details about users from this country.

What is the best approach to do it?
using mapPartitions? foreachPartition?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mapPartitions and foreachPartitition were for RDDs. Now Dataset can also use mapPartitions.

In general you should use the Spark DSL- or Spark SQL APIs on Dataframes or DataSets. These use Catalyst Optimizer implying less thinking to do and it also works in parallel mode. An example for a Dataframe is, similar to DataSet:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
//import org.apache.spark.sql._
//import org.apache.spark.sql.types._ 

val df = Seq(
 ("green","y", 4),
 ("blue","n", 7),
 ("red","y", 7),
 ("yellow","y", 7),
 ("cyan","y", 7)
          ).toDF("colour", "status", "freq")

val df2 = df.where("status = 'y'") 
            .select($"freq", $"colour")
            .groupBy("freq")
            .agg(collect_list($"colour"))

df2.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+----+--------------------+
|freq|collect_list(colour)|
+----+--------------------+
|4   |[green]             |
|7   |[red, yellow, cyan] |
+----+--------------------+
```

But as in case of RDDs you can use mapPartitions on a DS.